# SQL Query To Capture Starting and Ending Revision Status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write an SQL Server query where a specific ID can have multiple revisions, but I only want to pull the starting status and the current/end status. I don't necessarily care what happened along the way.

Here is a sample of the current database structure (I cannot assume the data will be sorted).

```
ID     REV    STATUS    CURRENT      NOTES
----------------------------------------------
1111    1     High       F        Note One
1111    2     High       F        Note Two
1111    3     Medium     F        Note Three
1111    4     Medium     F        Note Four
1111    5     Medium     F        Note Five
1111    6     Medium     F        Note Six
1111    7     Complete   T        Note Seven
2222    1     Medium     F        Note One
2222    2     High       F        Note Two
2222    3     Complete   T        Note Three
3333    1     Low        T        Note One
4444    1     Low        F        Note One
4444    2     Medium     T        Note Two
```

Here is my desired output.

```
ID      START STATUS      END STATUS     END NOTE
---------------------------------------------------
1111    High              Complete       Note Seven
2222    Medium            Complete       Note Three
3333    Low               Low            Note One
4444    Low               Medium         Note Two
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the lowest Revision always 1?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes. There will always be a REV = 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first I thought you just wanted the first and last rows and I hadn't noticed the `current` column...

```
    select * from 
        (
        select *
            row_number() over (partition by id order by rev asc) rnA,
            row_number() over (partition by id order by rev desc) rnD
        from <table> revs
        ) r
    where rnA = 1 or rnD = 1
```

After actually reading the question closer...

```
select
    id,
    min(case when rev = 1 then status end) as "Start Status",
    min(case when current = 'T' then status end) as "End Status",
    min(case when current = 'T' then status end) as "End Note"
from <table> rev
group by id
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Simple solution that I should have seen myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to get all the rows that are the current revision and then add the status from the first revision.  Here's one way:

```
SELECT ID, 
    (SELECT [STATUS] FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.ID = MyTable.ID AND t2.REV = 1) AS [START STATUS],
    [STATUS] AS [END STATUS], NOTES AS [END NOTE]
FROM MyTable
WHERE [CURRENT] = 'T'
```

You could also join on the first revision as well:

```
SELECT ID, 
    Rev1.[STATUS] AS [START STATUS],
    [STATUS] AS [END STATUS], NOTES AS [END NOTE]
FROM MyTable 
    INNER JOIN MyTable Rev1
        ON MyTable.ID = Rev1.ID 
            AND Rev1.REV = 1
WHERE MyTable.[CURRENT] = 'T'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID,
    iif(REV=1,STATUS,null) [START STATUS],
    iif(maxrev is null,null,STATUS) as [END STATUS],
    iif(maxrev is null,null,NOTES) as [END NOTE]
from <tablename,,> t1
left join (select ID, max(REV) maxrev from <tablename,,> group by ID) t2
    on t1.ID=t2.ID and t1.rev=t2.maxrev
group by ID,
    [START STATUS],
    [END STATUS],
    [END NOTE]
```

Comment: Why would `maxrev` ever be null? ;)

Comment: whoops should be a left join!

Comment: No, it wouldn't *ever* be null. It looks like you wrote a query for MySQL but I don't believe it will work as you intended. You're missing a `group by` in the `maxrev` query and your `iif()` conditions are a little off. I'd encourage you to play around with it though.

Comment: oops all over the place! With the group by in the inner select and joining on rev, maxrev will be null when the rev is not the max(rev)

Comment: You were on the right track. I hope you don't mind the help. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e256b/15